# Appcode shortcut key for "Scroll from source" ?

Tags: appcode

if you open a file in Appcode via a find or Shift + Cmd + O you don't see which folder that file is in in the project. in the project explorer there is a button on the top bar on the left that shows where the file is ( the icon looks like a cross - x ) called "scroll from source" if you hover over it. 
Anyone know what the shortcut key for it is? it is not in the listed Appcode shortcuts

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there isn't a single shortcut, but it can be done in two: Alt+F1, then Enter

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the shortcut, but in project explorer, next to the icon you've mentioned, there is a settings ('gear') icon, where you have an option to 'Autoscroll from source'. Every time you open file using Shift+Cmd+O it will show in project explorer automatically. Handy.

Comment: Thanks , its weird that it doesn't show in Project explorer in mine. (using shift cmd O ). Would still love to know if theres a handy shortcut key combo

Comment: After pressing Shift+Cmd+A you can type action or option and execute it - there are shortcuts shown as well. But I didn't find that one there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's Alt+F1( + fn if needed) then Enter, which you can find in the AppCode settings keyboard mapping as "Select in..." and can rebind as in Xcode with Cmd + Shift + J